# Two indexes in Ruby for loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop

can you have a ruby for loop that has two indexes?
ie:

```
 for i,j in 0..100
     do something
 end
```

Can't find anything in google

EDIT: Adding in more details

I need to compare two different arrays like such

```
Index:  Array1:  Array2:

   0       a        a
   1       a        b
   2       a        b 
   3       a        b
   4       b        b
   5       c        b
   6       d        b
   7       d        b
   8       e        c
   9       e        d
   10      e        d
   11               e
   12               e
```

But knowing that they both have the same items (abcde)
This is my logic in pseudo, lets assume this whole thing is inside a loop

```
#tese two if states are for handling end-of-array cases
If Array1[index_a1] == nil
    Errors += Array1[index_a1-1]
    break
If Array2[index_a1] == nil
    Errors += Array2[index_a2-1]
    break

#this is for handling mismach
If Array1[index_a1] != Array2[index_a2]

    Errors += Array1[index_a1-1] #of course, first entry of array will always be same

    if Array1[index_a1] != Array1[index_a1 - 1]
         index_a2++ until Array1[index_a1] == Array2[index_a2]
         index_a2 -=1 (these two lines are for the loop's sake in next iteration)
         index_a1 -=1

    if Array2[index_a2] != Array2[index_a2 - 1]
         index_a1++ until Array1[index_a1] == Array2[index_a2]
         index_a2 -=1 (these two lines are for the loop's sake in next iteration)
         index_a1 -=1
```

In a nutshell, in the example above,

```
 Errors looks like this
 a,b,e
```

As c and d are good.

Comment: Do you really need this loop? What are you trying to implement? Anyway, using enumerators would be better approach.

Comment: It wouldn't really make any sense. What are you trying to do? If you just want independent indices, use an index and a "regular" variable.

Comment: I'm looping through two arrays simultaneously and comparing them. I need diferent indexes as sometimes I need to skip a few elements in one of the arrays

Comment: @mhz Post what you need to do, not how you are attempting to implement it. Under what circumstances do you need to access the arrays not exactly in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop is not the best way to approach iterating over an array in Ruby. With the clarification of your question, I think you have a few possibly strategies.

You have two arrays, a and b. 
If both arrays are the same length:

```
a.each_index do |index|
 if a[index] == b[index]
   do something
 else
   do something else
 end
end
```

This also works if A is shorter than B.

If you don't know which one is shorter, you could write something like:

`controlArray = a.length < b.length ? a : b` to assign the controlArray, the use controlArray.each_index. Or you could use `(0..[a.length, b.length].min).each{|index| ...}` to accomplish the same thing.

---

Looking over your edit to your question, I think I can rephrase it like this: given an array with duplicates, how can I obtain a count of each item in each array and compare the counts? In your case, I think the easiest way to do that would be like this:

```
a = [:a,:a,:a,:b,:b,:c,:c,:d,:e,:e,:e]
b = [:a,:a,:b,:b,:b,:c,:c,:c,:d,:e,:e,:e]
not_alike = []
a.uniq.each{|value| not_alike << value if a.count(value) != b.count(value)}
not_alike
```

Running that code gives me `[:a,:b,:c]`.

If it is possible that a does not contain every symbol, then you will need to have an array which just contains the symbols and use that instead of a.uniq, and another `and` statement in the conditional could deal with nil or 0 counts.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that there is a common index for both a and b. Please see Edit. Thanks though

Comment: @mhz - please see revised answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the revised answer. I ended up doing a massive for-loop with 2 different indexes that worked. But your way makes much more sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate over two arrays using Enumerators instead of numerical indices. This example iterates over `a1` and `a2` simultaneously, echoing the first word in `a2` that starts with the corresponding letter in `a1`, skipping duplicates in `a2`:

```
a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
a2 = ["apple", "angst", "banana", "clipper", "crazy", "dizzy"]

e2 = a2.each
a1.each do |letter|
  puts e2.next
  e2.next while e2.peek.start_with?(letter) rescue nil
end
```

(It assumes all letters in `a1` have at least one word in `a2` and that both are sorted -- but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

> *the two arrays are praticatly the same except for a few elements that i have to skip in either/or every once in a while*

Instead of skipping during iterating, could you pre-select the non-skippable ones?

```
a.select{ ... }.zip( b.select{ ... } ).each do |a1,b1|
  # a1 is an entry from a's subset
  # b1 is the paired entry bfrom b's subset
end
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't know my non-skippables. They are not defined